# Create a timer / stopwatch and start after animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, timer, onkeypress

Hi I'm working on a project and I've been thinking about if there is possible to start a timer after an animation has finsihed, and stop the timer onkeypress ? And then just send the time results to another page ? And with timer I mean stopwatch so no counter or anything else...

Anyway here is the original code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Exercise1</title>
<style>
.first-child {
       width: 200px;
       height: 200px;
       background: white;
       margin-top: 150px;
       margin-bottom: 50px;
       margin-right: 0px;
       margin-left: 550px;
       -webkit-animation: myfirst 1s;
       animation: myfirst 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
       0% {background: white;}
      20% {background: white;}
      40% {background: white;}
      60% {background: white;}
      80% {background: white;}
     100% {background: red;}
}

.first-parent {
       color: blue;
       margin-top: 5px;
       margin-bottom: 50px;
       margin-left: 600px;
       margin-right: 0px;
}
.second-parent {
       color: red;
       margin-top: 0px;
       margin-bottom: 50px;
       margin-left: 40px;
       margin-right: 0px;
}
p {
       margin-left: 640px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class='first-child'></div>

<button class='first-parent' onclick="window.location.href='Exercise2.html' ">B</button>

<button class='second-parent' onclick="window.location.href='Exercise2.html' ">R</button>

<br />
<p>1/2</p>

<script>
document.onkeypress = function(b) {
      b = b || window.event;
      var charCode = b.charCode || b.keyCode,
      character = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

      console.log(charCode);
      window.location.href="Exercise2.html";
};

document.onkeypredss = function(r) {
      r = r || window.event;
      var charCode = r.charCode || r.keyCode,
      character = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

      console.log(charCode);
      window.location.href='Exercise2.html';
};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I don't got any timer yet... Sorry about that but if there is any questions just ask, I'm most familiar with HTML, CSS, JavaScript and I know some jQuery but if there's another way to do it I gladly hear that too. Thanks in advance, peace !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you've tagged jQuery, I will give you a jQuery solution.

A stopwatch can be created using the following JavaScript/jQuery:

```
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
    seconds = 0,
    t;
function add() {
    seconds++;
    h1.textContent = seconds;
    timer();
}
function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}
```

We then also need to define a `start()` and a `stop()` function which start and stop the timer:

```
// start and stop functions
function start() {
    timer();
}

function stop() {
    clearTimeout(t);
}
```

That's it! Now we've created a stopwatch.

In your question, you mention that you would like the stopwatch to *start* after an animation finishes. We can do this now by calling `.start()` in an animation's callback function like so:

```
// Example of an animation that starts the timer when complete
$("#animatedDiv").animate({
        left: "+=50",
        top: "+=150",
        height: "100px",
        width: "200px"
      }, 4000, function() {          // define a callback function

        // Animation complete.
        start();                    // Start the timer in the callback function
  });
```

Likewise, we can also `stop()` the timer upon a keypress:

```
// Example of a function that stops the timer
$(document).keypress(function( event ) {
  if ( event.which == 115 ) {       // when pressing s for 'stop'
     alert('You stopped the timer');
     stop();
  }
});
```

Now when we want to send the stopwatch's time to another page, we need to add the timer's value as a url parameter when directing to another page.

In general this is done as follows:

```
http://www.newpage.com/?myParameter=myValue
```

Where we send variable `myParameter` containing the value `myValue`.

In your example, we could do this as follows:

```
// button click function
$("#theButton").click(function() {
    window.open('http://www.yourpage.com/?time='+h1.textContent);
});
```

Where `h1.textContent` would then be the timer's value. The other page could then get the variable `time` from the url. If you don't know how to do this, read this:

- [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter)
- [Get url parameter jquery Or How to Get Query String Values In js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery)

I've put all of this together in a comprehensible jsFiddle:

## [jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fL8ake52/)

With that demo, it should be possible to achieve what you wanted to achieve.

[image]

Comment: Ok It didnt work when I tried the code but I think there might be a problem with my browser or something I'm using Google Chrome but I also tried in Firefox but it didnt work there either. I looked in the console and it says: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" in both Chrome and Firefox

Comment: @Nikki That means you didn't include jQuery. Search on Google for how to do that. Basically what you have to do is add a link to the jQuery file in a script declaration.

Comment: @Nikki And? Was it useful?

Comment: I don't really understand what u ment in the other comment, so at the moment no

Comment: @Nikki Search on Google on how to include jQuery in your code. Once you've done that, it'll work.

Comment: I've found this site: http://jquery.com/download/ but how do I know which one to chooose ?

Comment: You just have to link to it [like done here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp). Basically, you put `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` BEFORE your `</head>` tag in every page you want to use it.

Comment: Yeah it works thank you !! :) By the way would you mind to help me with another problem ? I don't really know how I can send which key that was pressed to another page or more or less another file, that I have on my computer ? Not redirecting I already know how to do that, but you know send the keypress to a "result file" or something like that.

Comment: @Nikki: With which language?

Comment: @JeanPaul if it's possible maybe with jQuery, JavaScript or HTML or something like that but if there's any other way to do it I would like to hear that to ! But if so, I need a detailed explenation.

Comment: @Nikki Ask a well-defined new question here on SO and post the link to the question in a comment here. Then I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @JeanPaul I've been writing a new post I haven't post it yet but should I link it to your post/answer on my question here ? just dubbelchecking  :p

Comment: @Nikki, that's not necessary as the question you're about to ask has no relation to this question ;)

Comment: @JeanPaul aha ok thanks :) Anyway I've posted it now just follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28011767/send-which-key-that-was-pressed-to-file