# Send which key that was pressed to file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I got a question that I would like to get some help with. First I was wondering how to detect which key that was pressed and then after that send the key that was pressed to another page or more or less another file that I have on my computer ? Not redirecting I already know how to do that, but more like send the keypress to a "result file" or something like that. So far I got a keypress that redirects to next page/file and when the user presses the button it logs the charCode to the console. But I want it to send the key to another file instead of sending it to the console. Here is my code so far:

jQuery:

```
document.onkeypress = function(b) {
         b = b || window.event;
         var charCode = b.charCode || b.keyCode,
         character = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

console.log(charCode);
window.location.href="Test3.html";
};
```

And I got two of those b and r. If there's a possible way to do it in jQuery or JavaScript it would be awesome, but if there's another way to do it in another language I need a detailed description.

Comment: you want to write in text file which key was pressed

Comment: You cannot write to files using javascripts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582268/read-write-to-file-using-jquery

Comment: You can write with php.

Comment: Ok is there any way for you to show me how ?

Comment: You can store to database or text files using php..

Comment: Huh ? I don't know php so I need like the code for how to do that :p

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.href="Test3.html/?charCode=" + charCode;
```

This will give your page 'Test3.html' access to the GET parameter 'charCode'.  Though you'd probably want to use a server-side language to do something useful with it, since IMO it is a bit of a hassle to manipulate GET parameters from javascript.

Comment: I tried this one to and it didn't make any differens from the original code, thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

### PHP

```
  <script>
     $(document).keypress(function(event){
     var key = event.keyCode;
  </script>
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo myphp.php ?>",
            data: {
                'events': key
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
            },
            complete: function()
            {        
            }
        });
```

### myphp.php

```
 $key = $_POST['events'];
 $myfile = fopen("filename.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
 fwrite($myfile, $key);
 fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: it returns ascii value of keypressed. You can check for which key was pressed.

Comment: Hi sorry that I haven't wrote back I've just been busy, anyway I tried the code and it didn't work, I couldn't see which key that was pressed but I'm not sure if I've been doing it right or not. But what I noticed it didn't work, thanks anyway !